# Javax and Inner class warning in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, inner-classes

I was created an android application and run the app, apk was build and application was running successfully. But in my Android Monitor application having 48 warning messages. I was tried lot of changes in **build.gradle** file in my past. But still the warning messages are appears. Here i will attach the screen shots of warning. Give me exact solution to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Error Snap 1]
[image: Error Snap 2]

Answer (score 2):

Try to adding the ProGuard config. That should fix the problem.

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: where to add this properties. in build Types or in any other?

Comment: proguard-rules.pro file in android app folder in project.

Comment: if it solve your problem then accept this answer . it help other person also.

Comment: ya i did. @Md Abdul Gafur

Comment: Sorry, Still i having same problem. Due to instant run it was not previously shown the error. is any alternative solution for the error?

Comment: also added -keepattributes EnclosingMethod